# php/Laravel - codepath is reached no matter the value of the conditional expression

Tags: php, laravel, boolean

I created a helper class named `UuidHelper` with a function named `IsValidUuid` that returns a bool value. I'm type-hinting it to return a bool.

```
public static function IsValidUuid($uuid) : bool {
    ...
}
```

I'm testing my code on a Homestead Vagrant box.

```
$isValid = \UuidHelper::IsValidUuid($employee_uuid);

if ($isValid)
    dd($isValid);
```

The `dd()` works as intended here, returning `true`, but when I negate the $isValid in the `if()` statement (this is the *only* change I'm making) like so:

```
if (!$isValid)
    dd($isValid);
```

The `dd()` now returns `false`. Why is the value of `$isValid` changing when I negate the expression in the `if()` statement? And why is the `dd()` running in both cases? This code path should not be reached.

Just for kicks I also tried the following instead of the NOT operator:

```
if ($isValid == false)
```

with the same results.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure the value of `$employee_uuid` hasn't changed? What happens when you run the same test you posted in the question, but dump (not die) `$employee_uuid` and `$isValid` before the `if` check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not calling the function multiple times - one of them might be passing in a bad UUID.

Comment: Eric you're a godsend, turns out I was calling the function for each Employee instance in my collection. So the employee I was testing with was not erroring out, but the second employee (fetched in the collection) was.